# Python design question: When dependencies can't be instantiated ahead of time

Tags: python, design-patterns

Sorry for the poor title but if I knew the class of problems I was tackling perhaps I could find an answer.

In an ideal situation, one creates an object with all its needed dependencies, and then uses the object. However in some cases, the information needed to create a dependency is not known before the object is used.

I will try to create a concrete example that has to do with making a house. The following will be the dependencies

```
class WallMakerAlgorithm(abc.ABC):
    def build(self):
        # Put specific algorithm here that will build the wall
        pass

class DoorMakerAlgorithm(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, color: float, material: str):
        # subclasses can override init to add more fancy stuff
        self.color = color
        self.material = material

    def build(self):
        # Put specific algorithm here that will build the door
        pass
```

These are used by a house builder class. In the ideal case, a `HouseBuilder` will know its dependencies on init:

```
class BasicHouseBuilder:
    def __init__(self, door_maker_algorithm: DoorMakerAlgorithm, wall_maker_algorithm: WallMakerAlgorithm):
        self.door_maker_algorithm = door_maker_algorithm
        self.wall_maker_algorithm = wall_maker_algorithm

    def build(self):
        self.wall_maker_algorithm.build()
        self.door_maker_algorithm.build()
```

But now assume that for some (contrived) reason, the customer hasn't decided on the color of the doors. They tell you that once the wall is built, they will know the color because they will be able to see it. This creates a chicken and egg kind of problem. I can't create the `HouseBuilder` because I can't create the door making algorithm, and I can't create the door making algorithm without actually running `HouseBuilder`. Something like this:

```
class DecideColorLaterHouseBuilder:
   def __self__(self, wall_maker_algorithm: WallMakerAlgorithm, query_color: Callbale, ???):
      self.wall_maker_algorithm = wall_maker_algorithm
      self.query_color = query_color
      ???

   def build(self):
      self.wall_maker_algorithm.build()
      desired_door_color = self.query_color()
      # Now I want to build the door. But I don't have the door algorithm because I don't know the color!
```

Is there some design pattern that deals with this kind of problem? Are my abstractions just messed up in general? I can potentially add `color` as an argument to `build` of the `DoorMakingAlgorithm` but that just messes up my abstractions.

Comment: Why not have a base color (when you maybe pass `color=None`) and then have a method called `add_color` or `change_color` - actually change might be better because then it includes the ability to change the color even when you have chosen something before!

Answer (score 0):

You could use default values for the arguments of your functions.

```py
class DoorMakerAlgorithm(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, material: str, color: float=0xffffff):
        # arguments with default values (optional arguments) must come after mandatory ones
        # Here I put white color, but you could put any other color, or even None
        # subclasses can override init to add more fancy stuff
        self.color = color
        self.material = material
```

Using None as a default value can allow you to through an exception in case the user still hasn't define the color when you build

```py
class DoorMakerAlgorithm(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, material: str, color: float=None):
        self.color = color
        self.material = material

    def build(self):
        if self.color is None:
            raise Exception(f"Color hasn't been defined yet for {self}")
        # Then proceed to build the wall
```

You can also use a property so that the user can change the color after instanciation while you still check the input. Note that in python, the user can always access any attribute of a class and modify them. The property allows you to secure the input, but the user can still modify the `_color` attribute and put anything in there. the `_` is a convention for attributes the end user shouldn't mess with.

```py
class DoorMakerAlgorithm(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, material: str, color: float=None):
        self.color = color
        self.material = material

    # You can use a property to allow the user to change the color later, and ensure input is correct
    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, color: float=None):
        self._color = color

    def build(self):
        if self.color is None:
            raise Exception(f"Color hasn't been defined yet for {self}")
        # Then proceed to build the wall

algo = DoorMakerAlgorithm("bricks")  # not giving a color
# algo.build()  # would through an exception
algo.color = 0xffffff
algo.build()  # works
```